# The plural of One

Tags: homework, gre

I have a statement:

> 'The writer says we must all feel excitement and strangeness at the idea of going to sea.'

Now I have to remove "we" here and replace it with "one" or any other third person.

What can I do? I am thinking of replacing 'we' with 'one' but is that good?

Comment: It is possible, sometimes, to pluralize *ones*. But what's wrong with *they*, anyway?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, and why you're asking it (this is not a site dedicated to help with homework and the like). Replacing 'we' with 'they' seems to fulfil your requirement - that's if you've stated it correctly. But 'We / they feel strangeness at . . .' sounds very unnatural.

Comment: Better be careful there could be a hidden intention in asking this question (probably in a writing exam).  

There's the ***all*** to take care of. So to preserve the sense,    

*we* --> *one*  

*we all* --> *?everyone*   

>?The writer says **everyone** must feel excitement and strangeness at the idea of going to sea.

Comment: Simply replacing *we* with *one* is, of course, not good. "One must all feel excitement" is quite obviously not English. Better alternatives are not exactly obscure, either — there just aren't that many "other third persons" to choose from. *They must all feel, everyone must feel*, and *everybody must feel* spring to mind, and that's about it.

Comment: The plural pronouns are "you" "we" and "they". Either one of them fits in the sentence. The impersonal pronoun, one, is a little too formal for this context and is best left for making suggestions and recommendations.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth True it's not obvious. The question seems to have been designed to be so.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The question is about the plural of *one*. Abhijeet's answer is correct.

Comment: meta: @RegDwigнt I think the question was so designed on purpose. The OP has already made himself clear by asking for the "plural of one" right there in the title. The answer is a bit tricky, though, not the question.

Comment: @Kris the question is unclear, and there are alternatives. "You" is just as acceptable: The writer said: "You must all feel excitement ..."

Answer (score 1):

"The writer says everyone must feel (or, must be feeling?) the excitement and strangeness at the idea of going to sea."

Comment: However, you must try to show the "how and why" of your answer.

Comment: I'm upvoting this answer because it's a good one, it fits and what's more, it left out "all" in the sentence. "...everyone must all feel excitement..." makes for an awkward sounding sentence. I also like the suggestion "must be feeling" which improves it further still.